# Replace element isn't working despite following all the steps. Coverting to Array isn't working either

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, replace, getelementsbyclassname

I am struggling to replace `h2` using JS. I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.`

I tried converting it:

```
let prevHeading = document.getElementsByClassName('my-title');
prevHeading = Array.from(prevHeading);
```

didn't work.

```
<body>
  <div id="outer-box" style="margin: 20px;">
    <h2 class="my-title">OLD TITLE</h2>
    <div class="inner-box">
      <ul class="main-list">
        <li class="list-item">List Item 1</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 2</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 3</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 4</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
const newHeading = document.createElement('h2');
newHeading.className = 'my-title';
newHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode('NEW TITLE'));
const prevHeading = document.getElementsByClassName('my-title');
const outerBox = document.querySelector('#outer-box');
outerBox.replaceChild(newHeading, prevHeading);
```

I could just use `prevHeading[0]` but I just wanna know why it isn't working.
It also works with:

```
const prevHeading = document.querySelector('.my-title');
```

Comment: Since you're really close to the answer just a hint: what's the difference between prevHeading and prevHeading[0] ? Log both to the console and see what you've got

Comment: You will always need to access the element by index to use it regardless of whether it's an array or not (replaceChild accepts nodes as arguments not arrays/collections). Also, your `Array.from` call is working as expected, converting the HTMLCollection to an Array.

Comment: (`.replaceChild()` takes two nodes as parameters)

Comment: @pilchard, I seem to have confused Arrays with Nodes :-). That's why I tried converting it.

Comment: @Corrl, I got `undefined` out of `prevHeading[0]`. What's more confusing is that it works when I give them both `id`, and  it doesn't work when they have `class`. I just don't understand :-(

Comment: Have a look at [this site](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom) listing the various ways via which you can access elements on the page. With some you get the node directly, others give you a HTML Collection or NodeList. That was the problem in your case. The function takes nodes as arguments and simply won't work with something different. *"parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'."* (Like a function expecting a number won't work with a string...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as posted so long as you access the individual node from the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```js
// This works to convert the HTMLCollection to an Array
let prevHeading_example = document.getElementsByClassName('my-title');
prevHeading_example = Array.from(prevHeading_example);
console.log('prevHeading array: ', prevHeading_example);

// This whole block works so long as you access the individual node 'prevHeading[0]'
const newHeading = document.createElement('h2');
newHeading.className = 'my-title';
newHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode('NEW TITLE'));

const prevHeading = document.getElementsByClassName('my-title');
const outerBox = document.querySelector('#outer-box');
outerBox.replaceChild(newHeading, prevHeading[0]); // <-- access node at index 0
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer-box" style="margin: 20px;">
    <h2 class="my-title">OLD TITLE</h2>
    <div class="inner-box">
      <ul class="main-list">
        <li class="list-item">List Item 1</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 2</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 3</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 4</li>
        <li class="list-item">List Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: as far as I understood, `replaceChild()` requires nodes to function and `getElementsByClassName` only returns **HTML Collection** so either I have to use node index or totally different method like `querySelector()`. Thank you, guys.

Comment: That is an accurate understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you complicated the things.

You can just use querySelector and InnerHtml to replace the title :

```
var title = document.querySelector(".my-title") ;
title.innerHTML = "NEW TITLE" ;
```

Comment: You may have noticed, I am new to JS and trying things out. I was more curious about why it wasn't working despite there were other options. Anyways, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Arguably the OP's solution is more robust and definitely a good excercise. `innerHTML` while simple is not always the best solution.

Comment: More to the point would be to simply replace the `textContent` of the returned element. `title.textContent = "NEW TITLE" ;`